# SoapUI property transfer from JSON response -- single response without any value

Tags: soapui

I am a fresh user for **soapUI**.

Now I have a response , is using json format and it also response from Json/raw.

How can I get this value to property transfer. Please help take a look.

```
response RAW :
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 08:33:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 32
Server: Apache Tomcat
```

I want to get value "**adecde96bdaff1d165c6fd3df61dea46**".

How to write script to get this value?

Thanks you so much.

Comment: your json response is simply `"adecde96bdaff1d165c6fd3df61dea46"`?

Answer (score 0):

In your Test Case;

1. Create a new Property Transfer step.
2. Add a new transfer
3. Select your Request Step as your source
4. Select Response or ResponseAsXML
5. Select the Property you wish to be the target

Comment: My problem is , only the json and raw response this value . XML is null.So I can't ResponseAsXML directly.

Comment: simple select "Response" it will return what you need.   Sometimes ResponseAsXML also works even if its not valid XML, but I'll save explaining that quirk for another question :)